# VBA Mail Merge from excel LIKE Statement

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I'm trying to run a mail merge from excel. below is my code but the SQL statement seems to be failing (Run-time error 4198 command failed).

```
  wdocSource.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
            Name:=strWorkbookName, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
            Revert:=False, _
            Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
            Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
            sqlstatement:="SELECT * FROM `Labels$` WHERE F2 LIKE '%-%' AND F3 > '0'"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I realized i was missing the reference to Microsoft word library

Comment: The other problem you might run into is if the F3 column is acctually numeric, in which case the F3 > '0' syntax would be invalid. There is a problem there because the way WOrd gets the data means that, depending on the actual values in the sheet, the F3 column may be treated as TEXT, *requiring* the syntax F3 > '0' and causing an error with F3 > 0, or NUMBER, requiring F3 > 0 and failing F3 > '0'.

Answer (score 0):

I realized i was missing the reference to Microsoft word library